# Invoking HP ePrint Android application

Tags: android

I am working on an android app that should invoke android HP ePrint application for wireless printing. For that purpose, I'm using code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.hp.android.print.PRINT");
intent.setPackage("com.hp.android.print");

startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

I am pretty sure that I didn't get intent's action right... Does anybody know what is the right action to invoke this HP ePrint application? And how can I pass the exact file to print (intent.putExtra(...)).

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After more than 10 hours, I managed to find the solution. Right code to invoke HP ePrint application is like this:

```
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile( f );
    Intent intent = new Intent ("org.androidprinting.intent.action.PRINT");
    intent.setDataAndType( uri, "text/plain" );
    context.startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Comment: this doesn't work (anymore?). It crashes the HP ePrint with a NullPointerException

Answer (score 1):

After my android 5.0.1 app has created a JPEG file, I use the following code to start a wireless print operation (via HP ePrint version 3.4):

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File("something.jpg"));
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

The code works cleanly, but every time I print something I have to manually set the paper size to 'A4' and paper type to 'plain'. (It defaults to 'photo'.)

I would be very interested in documentation on how to pass Intent parameters to HP ePrint.

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.