# Android Call print intent for HP e-print app cause RuntimeException: Unable to start activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I am going to develop an app for android tablets that also has the ability to print some local saved images with direct printing access (therefore without intervention of the internet). In particular, for testing my app, I use motorola xoom 2.

My intented call code is this:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("path to the existing image file");
Intent intent = new Intent ("org.androidprinting.intent.action.PRINT");
intent.setDataAndType( uri, "image/*" );
startActivityForResult(intent, CALL_PRINT_ID);
```

and I get the error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.imageprinter/com.example.imageprinter.MainActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=org.androidprinting.intent.action.PRINT....

I have installed the app Hp e-print and I activated it through the input of my e-mail address with the same results. I also tried different intent:
"org.androidprinting.intent.action.SEND" for example

What is wrong or what did I forget?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invoking HP ePrint Android application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15683657/invoking-hp-eprint-android-application)